# Getting exception while applying style in on button in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have 2 button on window. I am applying the style. but got this exception.

'Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.' Line number '38' and line position '7'.

My Code.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="btnconnect" Source="images/img-1.png" /> 
        <Image x:Key="btnshow" Source="images/img-2.png" />
        <Image x:Key="btnclick" Source="images/img-2clicked.png"/>
        <Style x:Key="buttonconnect" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource btnconnect}">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid x:Name="grid">
                            <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="2">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"></ContentPresenter>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Value="{StaticResource btnclick}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="grid" Value="0.25"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="buttonshow" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource btnshow}" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Margin="50 100 50 100" Style="{StaticResource buttonconnect}" Height="50" Width="120"/>
        <Button Margin="50 110 50 10" Style="{StaticResource buttonshow}" Height="50" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Setter Value="{StaticResource btnclick}" />
```

I think your forgot to specify the property on which the setter applies.

Although I'm not sure it would cause a runtime error.

Basically what you should do (ideally before posting) is try to remove as much code as you can while still being able to reproduce your issue, only then post your question with the simplified code if you still have no clue of where the error is coming from.

Comment: Ok sir. your answer is right. tell me one more thing. I am using a single grid this time. If I have a nested grid or another child inside the grid. In this case how I access that. currently <Grid x:Name="grid">
<Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="2">
<ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
VerticalAlignment="Center"
TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"></ContentPresenter>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>

Comment: Sir, if my answer is right, please mark it as 'Answer'. If you have any other question, please create another question (after you have tried and done some research : surprisingly you can access the Grid's Children through the Grid.Children property, inherited from Panel)